# Store a List of Integers in Python

Tags: python, list

I need to create a Python list that can store integers. I then need to be able to print out each of those integers using `print()` and then empty the list afterwards.

Comment: You should probably ask your follow-up question as a new question. But what do you mean about "splitting" integers? Integers don't have commas, only string representations of them do.

Comment: I want to print out each integer in my list not one at a time but rather all in one string, splitted by commas. So, I wanna take my_list=[5,2,4] and then print out literally "5,2,4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the_list=[] # create list
the_list.append(1) # add number
for x in the_list:
    print(x) # print number
the_list=[] # clear list
```

If you've got many integers, you can do the following:

```
a=open("file","r") # if they're in a file and written newline-separated
for x in a:
    the_list.append(int(x)) # add a value to list
a.close() # close file
for x in the_list:
    print(x) # print value line by line
the_list=list() # empty list
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [35]: L = [] # create empty list

In [36]: L.append(1)

In [37]: L.append(2) # this could go on for a while

In [38]: L
Out[38]: [1, 2]

In [39]: print(L)
[1, 2]

In [40]: for num in L:
   ....:     print(num)
   ....:     
1
2

In [41]: L = []  # clear the list
```

In response to [@jedward's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29065612/store-a-list-arraylist-of-integers-in-python/29065667?noredirect=1#comment46367092_29065667):

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    print(L[i])
```

will loop over the indices of `L`, and print the value at each index.
Similar to Java, Python also uses 0-based indexing (so `L[0]` is the first element in `L`)

Comment: And just to complete the loop (and shortcircuit future questions), `L[i]` accesses the `i`th element (0-indexed), `len(L)` gets the length / number of elements, `if L:` where `L` is a list evaluates to `False` if `L` is empty, `True` otherwise.

Comment: Don't use `range(len(L))` for looping over a list, use `for i, elem in enumerate(L)`.

Comment: @DanielPryden: While I agree, I didn't want to throw `enumerate` at a beginner. I was simply trying to demonstrate list indexing

Answer (score 0):

`l = list()`, `l = []` both create an empty list.

For functions on lists: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types